# Problem adding videos to panel

Tags: gwt

I have  code that creates video files(with given names in an output folder).I have buttons in my UI that add :

> panel.add(video1);
>   panel.add(video2);
>   panel.add(video3);
>   panel.add(video4);

(where video1=new HTML("embed src=path....")) and clear :

> panel.clear();

these videos from the UI.The problem is that it works fine for the first time .But if I repeat the actions add->clear->add->clear and so on I just see the quicktime toolbar[i.e. I just see the 4 videos first time and on all subsequent actions I  see the toolbar instead of videos].I think this might be due to adding a same file to the panel twice but I remove them from panel in my clear function[infact I delete the videos] .Any ideas/solutions?

```
onSuccess(){   
    GUI.panel.add(new HTML("embed src=\"Output/Output1.avi\" WIDTH=\"367\"   
        HEIGHT=\"375\" AUTOPLAY=\"false\" TARGET=\"QUICKTIMEPLAYER\"
        PLUGINSPAGE=\"http://www.apple.com/quicktime/\" />"));  
    //So on for video 2,3,4
}

onClear(){   
    GUI.panel.clear();  
    File f1 = new File("Output/Output1.avi");   
    if (f1.exists()) {
        boolean success=f1.delete();
    }  
    //and so on for 2,3,4
}
```

Comment: onSuccess(){
GUI.panel.add(new HTML("<embed src=\"Output/Output1.avi\"   WIDTH=\"367\" HEIGHT=\"375\"  AUTOPLAY=\"false\"  TARGET=\"QUICKTIMEPLAYER\" PLUGINSPAGE=\"http://www.apple.com/quicktime/\"   />"));
//So on for video 2,3,4
}  



  
                                    onClear(){
GUI.panel.clear();
File f1 = new File("Output/Output1.avi");
   if (f1.exists()){boolean success=f1.delete();}
//and so on for 2,3,4
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution .Everything was correct but i was using IE and it did not render properly.I used Mozilla and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing the issue, but in the `onClear`, which I assume is client side code, you're using the `File` class, since this code is running in the browser as JavaScript there is no file access possible. So the file check should be done on the server side. I guess it might work in development mode, since that runs plain Java (haven't tested it). But you should move that part to the server side.

Comment: Hi Hilbrand ,
Thanks for the reply.Yes I am already running the onClear code on the server side.Actually when the clear button is pressed in the UI it makes a RPC and invokes the onClear method in the server.